# Snippet editor window closes even when the closing confirmation dialog is cancelled

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

## Steps do reproduce the problem

When you are answering some question...

1. Click on the **`Code Snippet`** button or press <kbd>CTRL+M</kbd>
2. Click on the **`X`** at the corner or press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close the window
3. Choose **`OK`** to actually close the window
4. Repeat steps **#1** and **#2**
5. Click **`Cancel`** and ***the window will be closed anyway***

I tested in Chrome (last version) and Internet Explorer 10. It does not matter whether I am logged in or not.

Comment: @m0sa I found this bug on Stack Overflow in Portuguese. Please make sure that site is also fixed. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2386/227

Comment: Same on firefox @utluiz

Comment: @utluiz the code is the same on all sites, once the fix is deployed, all sites would get it.

Comment: @m0sa 6-8 weeks? (or did it turn out more complex than you thought? :-))

Comment: @ShadowWizard don't ask...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug was caused by the snippets code mirror script being loaded asynchronously, and our events handlers being attached in the loader's promise, which got them wired up in the wrong order each but the first time, when the script was actually loaded.

Fix is rolling out with build rev `2015.1.22.2987` on meta and `2015.1.22.2213` on sites.

Comment: Cool... since you so kindly asked me not to ask... what happened there? ;)

Comment: Thanks! I guessed it was something like this, but I gave up trying to debug. Minified code is too messy.